# $location.path() not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-tabset

I'm trying to use $location.path() inside of an $interval to automatically navigate from tab to tab on a timer.

However, whenever I call $location.path(x) it only reloads my current view.

My code is as follows:

**tabsController.js**

```
(function () {
    var injectParams = ['$location', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$interval', 'teleAiDiagnosticsConfig'];

    var TabsController = function ($location, $routeParams, $scope, $rootScope, $interval, teleAiDiagnosticsConfig) {
        var vm = this;

        $rootScope.autoNavInterval = {};
        $rootScope.AutoNavActive = false;

        $scope.tabs = [
            { link: '#!/vehicles', label: 'Vehicles', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/vehicle') !== -1) ? true : false) },
            { link: '#!/workzones', label: 'Workzones', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/workzone') !== -1) ? true : false) },
            { link: '#!/operatorStations', label: 'Operator Stations', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/operatorStation') !== -1) ? true : false) },
            { link: '#!/sessionStatus/123', label: 'Session Status (123)', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/sessionStatus') !== -1) ? true : false) }
        ];

        // find the tab that should be marked as active
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tabs.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.tabs[i].active == true) {
                $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($scope.selectedTab == undefined)
            $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[0];

        $scope.setSelectedTab = function (tab) {
            $scope.selectedTab = tab;
        }

        $scope.tabClass = function (tab) {
            if ($scope.selectedTab == tab) {
                return "active";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        $scope.nextTab = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tabs.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.tabs[i] == $scope.selectedTab) {
                    if (i == $scope.tabs.length - 1) {

                        $location.path($scope.tabs[0].link);
                        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()

                        $scope.tabs[0].active = true;
                        $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[0];
                        break;
                    }

                    else {

                        $location.path($scope.tabs[i + 1].link);
                        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()

                        $scope.tabs[i + 1].active = true;
                        $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[i + 1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $scope.startAutoNav = function () {
            $rootScope.AutoNavActive = true;
            $rootScope.autoNavInterval = $interval(function () {
                $scope.nextTab();
            }, teleAiDiagnosticsConfig.autoNavTimer);
        }

        $scope.stopAutoNav = function () {
            $rootScope.AutoNavActive = false;
            $interval.cancel($rootScope.autoNavInterval);
        }

        $scope.startAutoNav();
    };

    TabsController.$inject = injectParams;

    angular.module('teleAiDiagnostics').controller('TabsController', TabsController);
}());
```

Yes, yes, I know using $rootScope is not advised. I'm going to change it once I get $location.path() working.

I've tried it with and without the `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()` lines. I've also tried adding a call to `$location.replace()` but this doesn't do anything for me.

Whenever $location.path() is called the view section flashes but it just reloads the Vehicles view.

[image]

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('teleAiDiagnostics', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        var viewBase = 'app/views/';

        $routeProvider
            .when('/vehicles', {
                controller: 'VehiclesController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'vehicles.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/vehicle/:id', {
                controller: 'VehicleController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + "vehicle.html",
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/workzones', {
                controller: 'WorkzonesController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'workzones.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/workzone/:id', {
                controller: 'WorkzoneController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + "workzone.html",
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/operatorStations', {
                controller: 'OperatorStationsController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'operatorStations.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/operatorStation/:id', {
                controller: 'OperatorStationController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'operatorStation.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/sessionStatus/:id', {
                controller: 'SessionStatusController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'sessionStatus.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/vehicles' });
    }]);

    // Intialize slider
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        slideshow: true,
        pauseOnAction: true,
        controlNav: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        touch: true,
        directionalNav: false,
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slideshowSpeed: 6000,
        smoothHeight: true
    });


}());
```

Not sure why this isn't working. I've followed all the tips I could find and I'm still getting the same result. I'm tempted to just add UI-Router to my application and replace my routes with states.

Comment: When you are calling `$location.path($scope.tabs[i + 1].link)` you are passing path with prefix. Can you try removing it and see if it helps? Something like `$location.path($scope.tabs[i + 1].link.replace('#!', ''))`.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav. Looks like we both figured it out at the same time.

Comment: Glad it works. Btw, why do you use `$scope` together with controllerAs `var vm = this;`? And I don't see why do you really need `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`.

Comment: The var vm = this is just a convention I started the project with. I'm in the process of removing those.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The issue was related to the hash-bang (#!) in the URL.

I added a link to my tab definitions which does not contain the hash-bang and it works perfectly now.

**tabsController.js**

```
(function () {
    var injectParams = ['$location', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$interval', 'teleAiDiagnosticsConfig'];

    var TabsController = function ($location, $routeParams, $scope, $rootScope, $interval, teleAiDiagnosticsConfig) {
        var vm = this;

        $rootScope.autoNavInterval = {};
        $rootScope.AutoNavActive = false;

        $scope.tabs = [
            { link: '#!/vehicles', refLink: '/vehicles', label: 'Vehicles', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/vehicle') !== -1) ? true : false) },
            { link: '#!/workzones', refLink: '/workzones', label: 'Workzones', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/workzone') !== -1) ? true : false) },
            { link: '#!/operatorStations', refLink: '/operatorStations', label: 'Operator Stations', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/operatorStation') !== -1) ? true : false) },
            { link: '#!/sessionStatus/123', refLink: '/sessionStatus/123', label: 'Session Status (123)', active: (($location.$$url.indexOf('/sessionStatus') !== -1) ? true : false) }
        ];

        // find the tab that should be marked as active
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tabs.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.tabs[i].active == true) {
                $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($scope.selectedTab == undefined)
            $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[0];

        $scope.setSelectedTab = function (tab) {
            $scope.selectedTab = tab;
        }

        $scope.tabClass = function (tab) {
            if ($scope.selectedTab == tab) {
                return "active";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        $scope.nextTab = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tabs.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.tabs[i] == $scope.selectedTab) {
                    if (i == $scope.tabs.length - 1) {

                        $location.path($scope.tabs[0].refLink);
                        $location.replace();
                        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()

                        $scope.tabs[0].active = true;
                        $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[0];
                        break;
                    }

                    else {

                        $location.path($scope.tabs[i + 1].refLink);
                        $location.replace();
                        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()

                        $scope.tabs[i + 1].active = true;
                        $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[i + 1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $scope.startAutoNav = function () {
            $rootScope.AutoNavActive = true;
            $rootScope.autoNavInterval = $interval(function () {
                $scope.nextTab();
            }, teleAiDiagnosticsConfig.autoNavTimer);
        }

        $scope.stopAutoNav = function () {
            $rootScope.AutoNavActive = false;
            $interval.cancel($rootScope.autoNavInterval);
        }

        $scope.startAutoNav();
    };

    TabsController.$inject = injectParams;

    angular.module('teleAiDiagnostics').controller('TabsController', TabsController);
}());
```

Hope this helps someone.